# iPython Notebook - What provides function definition using <TAB>

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Using Anaconda's iPython Notebook i can use  to get a pop-up with the function definition, as long as the appropriate import statement has been executed.

I've since removed anaconda because it makes a mess of all my other python projects, and have opted instead to set up a separate virtualenv for Data Analysis.

How do i configure my environment to do tab-completion like anaconda's version?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, ipython notebooks aren't specific to Anaconda, and the tab-completion is a feature of ipython in general.  If you execute ipython or ipython notebook you should still have tab-completion without Anaconda.  If you don't have ipython, you can get it by using:

```
pip install ipython
```

If you have your own code, tab-completion will work automatically, but if you want to customize what it shows, define a method that looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    return ["first_property_name", "second_name", "something_else"]
```

Here's a [link to the ipython docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html) about it.